# Returning the greatest key strictly less than the given key in a C++ Map

Tags: c++, stl

Is there a way the C++ STL Maps support this, since lower_bound and upper_bound on maps strictly return the value greater than the passed value.

[Lower key](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/NavigableMap.html#lowerKey(K))

Use case I have a map with times as keys in a sorted manner so in a MAP

```
time t1   = value1
time t2   = value2
time t2.5 = value3
```

In this case if I pass to this MAP t2.3 then it should give me value2. Does doing a lower_bound on the map and going back one element equivalent to the  "returning greatest key strictly less than given key" i.e

```
iterator = map.upper_bound(2.3)
and then 
iterator--;
```

Answer (score 34):

Yeah, lower_bound can be used for that, i've seen it before and used it like that.

```
map_type::iterator it = map.lower_bound(2.3);
if(it != map.begin()) {
    --it;
    // it now points at the right element
}
```

Would actually return the greatest, yet smaller (if it != map.begin() was true) one. If it was at .begin, then there is no smaller key. Nice idea from the comments is to return `.end` if there is no element that's less and pack this stuff into a function:

```
template<typename Map> typename Map::const_iterator 
greatest_less(Map const& m, typename Map::key_type const& k) {
    typename Map::const_iterator it = m.lower_bound(k);
    if(it != m.begin()) {
        return --it;
    }
    return m.end();
}

template<typename Map> typename Map::iterator 
greatest_less(Map & m, typename Map::key_type const& k) {
    typename Map::iterator it = m.lower_bound(k);
    if(it != m.begin()) {
        return --it;
    }
    return m.end();
}
```

The template should work for `std::set` too.

Comment: I'd imagine you'd want to return end() as a signal that lower_bound() returned begin() if you were going to pack this in a function (sounds like what the OP was going to do)

Comment: Why didn't they just impelement this function rather than giving us two functions that almost work the exact same? In fact, lower_bound is a completely misleading name if the key doesn't already exist

Answer (score 9):

If you don't care about the ordering, you can use map::upper_bound to get the element you want, but you need to define the map class with std::greater for the traits argument, so that the ordering is high-to-low.

```
typedef std::map<double,MyClass,std::greater<double> > MyMap;
MyMap myMap;
myMap[1.5] = value1;
myMap[2.0] = value2;
myMap[3.0] = value3;

MyMap::iterator elt = myMap.upper_bound(2.5); // should be pair(2.0,value2)
```

Answer (score 4):

Your method will work, but you need to check to make sure you don't back over the beginning of the map. Plus you need lower_bound, not upper_bound.

```
iterator = map.lower_bound(2.3)
if (iterator != map.begin())
    --iterator;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use std::find_if() with reverse iterators, something like:

```
find_if( map.rbegin(), map.rend(), is_less_than );
```

You'll have to define the is_less_than() predicate function.

(cf. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find_if.html)

Comment: This is O(n) operation.

Answer (score -2):

I always find to compute floor(x) and ceil(x) to be patricularly useful

```
floor(x) -> greatest element <=x 
ceil(x) -> smallest element >= x

floor_it = m.lower_bound(x); 
if (floor_it != m.end() && floor_it->first != x)
      --floor_it;

ceil_it = m.upper_bound(x);
if (ceil_it != m.end() && (ceil_it-1)->first == x)
    --ceil_it;
```