# How do perform a generic print for key type and map

Tags: c++, dictionary, printing

With reference to this question [StackoVerflow 529831](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529831/returning-the-greatest-key-strictly-less-than-the-given-key-in-a-c-map), this was one of the suggested approaches

```
template<typename Map> typename Map::const_iterator 
greatest_less(Map const& m, typename Map::key_type const& k) {
    //How to print K and Map m
    typename Map::const_iterator it = m.lower_bound(k);
    if(it != m.begin()) {
      return --it;
    }
    return m.end();
}
```

I would be interested in printing key K and Map m, How would go about this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `<<` operator, making sure that `<<` is defined for both your `Map::key_type` and `Map::data_type` types (you will know if that is not the case as the code will not compile.)

```
cout << k << endl;
for (typename Map::const_iterator it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); ++i) {
  cout << it->first << " -> " << it->second << endl;
}
```

e.g. if your `Map::data_type` is a `struct fraction` with members `float numerator` and `float denominator`,

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const fraction& obj) {
   return os << obj.numerator << '/' << obj.denominator;
}
```

Comment: +1 for letting the compiler tell you if you need to write operator<<.