# How to return the greatest key strictly less than the given key in a std::multimap?

Tags: c++, stl, multimap, lower-bound

`multimap` offers the methods `lower_bound` and `upper_bound`. Both may return an iterator to a value with key greater than the desired, with `lower_bound` possibly yielding exactly the desired.

Now I want an iterator to a value where the key is strictly *less* the requested. If it were a `map` rather than `multimap`, this would be relatively simple to achieve as described here:
[Returning the greatest key strictly less than the given key in a C++ Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529831/returning-the-greatest-key-strictly-less-than-the-given-key-in-a-c-map).
But in a `multimap`, decrementing an iterator is not guaranteed to make it point to a strictly smaller key. So I would need to decrement repeatedly, until a smaller key is found. Not particularly nice.

Is there a more elegant way of doing this?

The keys will in general be floating-point.

---

My apologies, it turns out that you *can* actually do it with a single decrement. I just placed it wrong in my program, that was the real error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lower_bound` points to the smallest element greater than or equal to the argument (or `end`). Thus decrementing it once gives you the desired element (if it exists).

Comment: I thought so, and it certainly works in `map`, but doesn't seem to in a `multimap`. Unless the error actually lies somewhere else, let me check again...

Comment: Are you sure you're not bumping into floating point rounding issues where you think you should have the same floating point number (so i.e., multiple keys with the same value), but your keys are actually a little different by a very, very small percentage?

Comment: It does indeed seem to be another problem, but it certainly has to do with the multimap an its lower_bound method. I'm still uncertain.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK, lower/upper_bound will return iterator to FIRST element of this value, So you can decrease it

Comment: `upper_bound` returns an iterator pointing to the first element of the *next* value, so decrementing that gives an iterator pointing to an instance of the argument (if it exists).