# How to find the first value less than the search key with STL set?

Tags: c++, stl

For example I have set of values in `std::set`:

```
{1, 2, 3, 5, 6}
```

And a search key, let it be 4, I want to find the first val. less than search key, 3 in this case, how to do it?

In Java there're functions `greater()`, `lower()` in `TreeSet`

Comment: It should be greatest value less than search key.

Comment: There's already a templated function which works with both `std::map` and `std::set`. http://stackoverflow.com/a/529916/817441

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Simply find the [lower_bound](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/lower_bound/) for that key and then decrement it once.

```
set<int> a;
set<int>::iterator it = a.lower_bound(5);
if (it != a.begin()) {
  it--;
  cout << *it << endl;
} else {
  cout << "No smaller element found!" << endl;
}
```

You can find a complete example [here](http://ideone.com/u3VzUH).

Comment: It's a bit redundant to say "decrement by one". Set iterators are not random access, you can't decrement them by 2. (`-=2` doesn't even compile).

Comment: What is the time complexity of this code? This is crucial information for everyone involved in competetive programming.

Comment: @StLuke5 `lower_bound` is guaranteed to be with logarithmic complexity. Following operations are constant, so overall complexity of the snippet is `O(log(n))`

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev That helps a lot, I was never sure as to whether it is O(log(n)) or more, since set dosnt have random access

Comment: @StLuke5 most implementations are based on red-black trees and lower_bound in this data structure is `O(log(n))`, although it does not support random access. I think what confuses you is that you expect that the method is implemented using binary search while it is not

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev Yes, that was exactly what confused me, thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 2):

You can use [lower_bound](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/lower_bound/) and then go one back i.e.

```
auto it = set.lower_bound(4);
if(it != set.begin())
{
  --it;
}
else
{
   //Add error handling
}
```

Comment: This one will result in exception if `lower_bound` returns first element

Comment: @Naveen `set` is a horrible name for a variable in `c++`. I like the use of `auto`. You may consider adding a comment this is c++11 solution.